# Date Time to Seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net

C# code to convert **date and time** format to **seconds**.
eg: 2013-04-03 01:00:00 to 1364950800

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking for the Unix file time (i.e. since 1 Jan 1970):

```
var unixFileTimeOrigin = DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01");
var date = DateTime.Parse("2013-04-03 01:00:00");

Console.WriteLine((date - unixFileTimeOrigin).TotalSeconds);
>>> 1364950800
```